# Loop custom type object ion procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created the following type:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE  "MY_CUSTOM_TYPE" AS OBJECT (
      my_num      NUMBER,
      my_char    VARCHAR2(3000)
    )
```

Inside of a procedure then I accept this parameter and want to loop through it:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE my_proc(
P_MY_TYPE IN MY_CUSTOM_TYPE
)
BEGIN

  FOR i IN P_MY_TYPE.FIRST .. P_MY_TYPE.LAST
  LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line( P_MY_TYPE(i).my_num || ' ' ||  P_MY_TYPE(i).my_char);
  END LOOP;

END;
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
PLS-00302: component 'FIRST' must be declared
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to loop through.  You created a custom type but that's a scalar.  There is no `first` or `last`.  Perhaps you intended to create a second type that was a collection of `my_custom_type` and to pass that to your procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you want to create a collection type

```
create type my_custom_collection
    as table of my_custom_type;
```

and then pass that collection to your procedure

```
create or replace procedure my_proc(
  p_collection my_custom_collection
)
as
begin
  for i in 1..p_collection.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( p_collection(i).my_num || ' ' ||
                          p_collection(i).my_char );
  end loop;
end my_proc;
```

If that is not what you are looking for, please edit your question to explain what exactly you are trying to loop over.  An object type is a scalar so it doesn't make sense to try to call `first` or `last` on it or to try to access the i<sup>th</sup> element.